# crypt() not functioning as needed

Tags: php, crypt

I'm using crypt as follows:

```
$pass = crypt($pass, 'd4');
```

for both insertion and validation of a password against a mysql table.  Problem is that if the passwords are similar it generates a similar result.  Is there an algorithm that guarantees different results for different passwords?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) and choose hashing algorithm that suits you well (if possible something stronger than MD5, but don't go all the way to SHA512 either)

On [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)'s manual page you will find this:

> The standard DES-based crypt() returns the salt as the first two
>   characters of the output. It also only uses the first eight characters
>   of str, so longer strings that start with the same eight characters
>   will generate the same result (when the same salt is used).

which should explain why you get same results.

Comment: What about the sha1() function with output set to raw (which is 20 characters) - nope php.net recomends against it because it is too fast, computationally inexpensive.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) is fine, as long as you *don't* use the old DES-based mode (`CRYPT_STD_DES`).  The only valid reason to use that is for interoperability with legacy software that uses such password hashes.

Instead, use the `CRYPT_BLOWFISH`, `CRYPT_SHA256` or `CRYPT_SHA512` modes.  These are modern password hashing algorithms that accept arbitrarily long passphrases, use long salts and support key strengthening via multiple iterations.

Unfortunately, the PHP `crypt()` interface is somewhat awkward: the only way to explicitly choose the algorithm you want is by supplying a correctly formatted `$salt` parameter, which means you also have to generate the actual salt yourself.  That's probably still easier and safer than rolling your own password hashing code, though.

Comment: crypt is effective because it generates a random salt and stores it in the encrypted password.  Hence your salt is as safe as your password is.

Comment: @Chris: Unfortunately, with the current PHP crypt() interface, if you want to choose the algorithm your also *have to* choose the salt yourself too.  If you leave the second parameter out, you do get a random salt, but you also get the system default algorithm (which might be the crappy DES-based one).  Oh, well... PHP sucks, film at 11.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a salt. Typically though if you're storing passwords you'll want to hash them, not encrypt them. There's load of stuff you can learn about this if you search for it (like on Google).

Answer (score 1):

from the php crypt() page:

> The standard DES-based crypt() returns the salt as the first two characters of the output. It also only uses the first eight characters of str, so longer strings that start with the same eight characters will generate the same result (when the same salt is used).

You may also want to use a different method of crypt such as MD5 or SHA256 as these are often preferable to DES.